# jQueryUI Autocomplete display "other" on dropdown when there is no match and let users be able to choose it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, frontend

I am trying to get an "other" choice to show up on autocomplete when user inputs something that has no matches from source. and let users be able to choose it. is there any way this would be possible?

this is my current code:

```
$( "#brand" ).autocomplete({
    source: brand,
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 0,
    autofocus: true,
    response: function(e, ui) {
        if (ui.content.length === 0){
            //got stuck here
        }
    }
})
```

i am stuck and any suggestions or inputs would be greately appreciated.. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your code to detect the lack of matching options is valid. To add the new option to the list you can use `ui.content.unshift()`, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var tags = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"];

  $("#brand").autocomplete({
    source: tags,
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 0,
    autofocus: true,
    response: function(e, ui) {
      if (ui.content.length === 0) {
        ui.content.unshift({
          value: "Other",
          label: "Other"
        });
      }
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="brand">
```

Comment: this is a simple and clean solution. thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, glad to help